# How can I set a background color for a HTML tag?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am completely new to HTML. I am getting a problem while applying background color to the header element. It is showing like this.

[image]

It is not applying to the ul elements. Here is
my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

header {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <h1>ABC reviews</h1>
  <ul class="log">
    <li>login</li>
    <li>sign up</li>
  </ul>

</header>
```

Comment: Can you specify what you want? Do you want the pink to be extended down to also cover the list items? Or do you want the list items to move up until they are in the hotpink background color?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I cannot be sure this question is not a duplicate; what I'm absolutely sure about is the question has nothing to do with `clearfix`. OP complains about the bgcolor not being inherited; they never mention positioning issues. A dupe hammer holder has a big resposability, and should read the questions they close instead of just looking at the images...

Comment: @RobertoCaboni (1) no where in the question there is the use of *inherit* or *inherited* (2) the background is not being applied to ul because there is the use of float and this is a common and known issue that you can fix using *clearfix*. Before blaming people about not reading the question, I advise you to first *read* the duplicate and get more detail about the issue and for your information adding `overflow:auto` to the `header` is the solution (the solution is not to use background:inherit to the ul) and this is what we call a clearfix.

Comment: @TemaniAfif (1) of course there's not _inherit_ in the question: if the OP would have known it they wouldn't have asked the question (2) again,the reason why the question was asked is that OP wasn't aware of the fact that bgcolor isn't inherited.- An answer should explain the mistake instead of trying to assume what the OP was going to do. `overflow: auto` produces a different result of `background-color: inherit`: whole height filled instead of just the list items. But OP's complain is about _"It is not applying to the ul elements."_ Where in the question they ask for the whole height filled?

Comment: @TemaniAfif summarizing, imho the _missing info_ is the `inherit` keyword knowledge, and my answer (tries) to go in that direction (you could explain it better, I'm sure). But for the same reason the duplicate target (which I _read_ before posting) is wrong.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni can you explain why the background is being applied to `h1`? is there inheritance in this case? no. Background of a parent element should cover all the child elements and it's not the case for ul due to the float making the ul rendred outside because there is a lack of clearfix. You are free to think the duplicate is wrong and there is a button to vote to reopen and if 2 other users agree with you it will get reopened (I will not discuss further more, this is not the purpose of comments)

Comment: @TemaniAfif In case of `h1` there's not inheritance but just transparency. Not all children elemets occupy the same space of the parent: in those case transaprency isn't enough. I expanded my answer in order to include this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You must change only a line

```
header ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px;
    direction: rtl; // old version is =>> float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `background-color` property [is not inherited from the parent tag](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp):

> **Default value:**    transparent
> **Inherited:**    no

On the other hand, as you can see in the quoted section, the default value value is **transparent**, meaning that the child element has the same background color of the **underlying** element.

Please note how *the underlying element* can be different than *the parent element*.

That's why, in your code, the `h1` background color is *hotpink*. It's background color hasn't been inherited from `header`; it is transparent and *fortunately* it has hotpink background color because the underlying element is `header`.

But it is not true as a general rule. That's what happens to your list, kicked out from the space occupied by the `header` (understanding if it was your real intention or not is beyond the scope of this answer) so it has `background-color: transparent` being displayed with a white background color.

According to your actual needs, order to have the same color of the parent in the children elements, you can make sure the parent's height expands to include the list elements too (as explained by the other answers).
Otherwise you can use `inherit` keyword in the children elements style:

```
background-color: inherit;
```

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

This solution (as well as explicitly defining the background color for each child element...) is valid also in the general case in which the position of the children is outside parent's block area.

Answer (score 0):

You should need something like that:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header{
  background-color: hotpink;
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header ul {
  margin-right: auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <h1>ABC reviews</h1>
  <ul class="log">
    <li>login</li>
    <li>sign up</li>
  </ul>

</header>
```